# Screw Modifier Destroying Normal in Blender

Tags: modeling, modifiers, screw-modifier

For some reason whenever I use a screw modifier my normals are being destroyed. 
The below image is before applying screw modifier
[image]

Now after adding screw modifier, it looks like this
[image]

I have made sure all the transforms have been applied. Is there a way to correct this quickly?

Comment: I think for that the screw will always give bad result, because it creates edges between the start and end of the mesh at every iteration. You can see it for yourself if you lower the Angle below 360°. What you need is either an Array modifier + Rotated empty or an array modifier + a curve modifier

Comment: Hey :). Screw modifier works best with single edges and no faces. Reduce the mesh to a single edge, and it will work very well.

Comment: Ok, thanks! it worked with edges :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone who might have the same problem. The screw modifier doesn't work well with faces. So have only edges or vertices when adding screw modifier
[image]
[image]

Here is a workaround for that problem if you really want to use the screw modifier with faces.

- step1: select your object
- step2: Add screw modifier
- step3: add solidify modifier
- step4: play around with offset and clamp in the solidify modifier
  until you get normal in the right direction.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hello :). Check *Calc Order* and your normals should work fine straight away.

Comment: Well I tried and it didn't

Answer (score 2):

Just to add to the existing answer.

You can control face orientation in the *Screw modifier*.
By checking *Calc order* (corrects normals) and using the *Flip* option (flips normals).

[image]

Comment: yes this works with edges but not with faces

Answer (score 0):

If your mesh or part(s) of your mesh have flipped normals, here is what you can do :

- Select your object and enter *Edit Mode*
- Activate the *Calculate Order* option in the *Screw* modifier tab
- Select the part of the mesh which shows flipped normals
- Press the <kbd>Space Bar</kbd>(or <kbd>F3</kbd>) and search for the  *Mirror* (*X/Y/Z Local*) function
- Expand bottom left  *Mirror* menu, then *Orientation* and choose *Normal*(instead of Local)
- Find the axis that works for you (X, Y or Z)

[image]